# Flexbox container with children that have a set top value but still behave like in a flexBox along the X-axis

Tags: html, css, flexbox

HTML

```
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="booking blue"></div>
  <div class="booking green"></div>
  <div class="booking purple"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
}

.booking {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  top: 50%;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.purple {
      background-color: purple;
      top: 50%;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/s_berg/pen/zYqYaWW

The goal from the drop box example for the blue box to have 100% width (of the red box) and the purple and green box should each be 50% wide of the red container. Atm they each take 1/3 of the width.

I basicly want to get the behaviour from a flexbox along the X-axis, as in the children take up 100% width if they are alone and share the space and take 50% width if they share the same postion as another child along the Y-axis.

However I wanna set a certain top value for each box, like in the cope pen example, except I want the boxes to take 100% width since they are alone in that area along the Y-axis. Can this be achieved with only CSS and HTML or do I need to involve JS for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-basis` for the containers.

**If blue, green, and purple are present:**

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.booking {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.green {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 100vh / 2);
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.purple {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 100vh / 2);
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="booking blue"></div>
    <div class="booking green"></div>
   <div class="booking purple"></div>
</div>
```

**If only blue and green are present**: (same css, just removed the purple div from the html)

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.booking {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.green {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 100vh / 2);
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.purple {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 100vh / 2);
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="booking blue"></div>
    <div class="booking green"></div>
</div>
```

*Note: Check it on full page, the red container is there.*

Comment: And no way to achieve this behaviour with only one flex-box? Cause this kinda mess the top value. I need to do this with a dynamic amount of .booking div's and they need to be at a very specific height of the red box =/ Maybe I to use absolute position and calculate the position of each box instead.

Comment: I've came up with another idea and updated my answer. Check it out. @SebastianBerg

Comment: Yes! That is absolutley a step in the right direction, think I can work with that. Thanks.